# Is there a way to get my BackgroundImage to fill the ContentPage evenly? Xamarin.Forms, XAML

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Here's my current code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Quickies" x:Class="Quickies.QuickiesPage" BackgroundImage="Overview Image.png">
</ContentPage>
```

Is there a property I can set in XAML to make the image fill the page evenly? It's cutoff right now:

[[image: 1]]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this probably it would help you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Quickies" x:Class="Quickies.QuickiesPage">
<Grid Padding="0">
    <Image
        Aspect="AspectFill"
        Source="Overview Image.png"
        RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width}"
        RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint= "{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height}">
    </Image>
</Grid>
</ContentPage>
```

Comment: Yes, I was able to achieve what I wanted with the same code. I just wanted to know if there is a way to make it happen with some other property. I'm starting to think that there isn't.

Comment: @msloan11 I had searched for other solution, but ended up with this.